# kotlin how does the checking of a nullable boolean work?

Tags: kotlin, nullable, equality

Having a class `Config` with nullable boolean `sAllowed` and a interface function returns a nullable Config

```
interface IConfig {
    fun getConfig() : Config?
}

class Config (var sAllowed: Boolean?=null)
```

and when want to use this boolean:

```
var sAllowed = false
// some loop ...
    val config = iConfig.getConfig()
    if (config != null) {
        sAllowed = sAllowed || config.sAllowed == true
    }
```

but the `config.sAllowed == true` translates to:

```
Intrinsics.areEqual(config.getsAllowed(), true);
```

and the `Intrinsics.areEqual(config.getsAllowed(), true);`
is:

```
public static boolean areEqual(Object first, Object second) {
    return first == null ? second == null : first.equals(second);
}
```

the `first.equals(second);` is :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

the doc for `equals(Object obj)` is `Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one`, not the value equality.

Is it sounds like the `config.sAllowed == true`  is checking object equality not value, or what am I missing here?

````
     * The {@code equals} method for class {@code Object} implements
     * the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects;
     * that is, for any non-null reference values {@code x} and
     * {@code y}, this method returns {@code true} if and only
     * if {@code x} and {@code y} refer to the same object
     * ({@code x == y} has the value {@code true}).
     * <p>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking Object equality. However look at the `equals()` of `Boolean.java`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
            return value == ((Boolean)obj).booleanValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This does consider the value wrapped by the Wrapper class.

```
first.equals(second);
```

Will invoke `equals` on `Boolean` and not `Object` since `first` is a `Boolean`.